# PHP OOP: Get all declared classes which are have extended another parent class

Tags: php

I need to get all declared classes which are have extended another parent class.

So for example...

```
class ParentClass {

}

class ChildOne extends ParentClass {

}

class ChildTwo extends ParentClass {

}

class ChildThree {

}
```

I need an array that outputs this:

```
array('ChildOne', 'ChildTwo')
```

I'm new to PHP OOP, but based on some Googling, I came up with this solution.

```
$classes = array();

foreach( get_declared_classes() as $class ) {
    if ( is_subclass_of($class, 'ParentClass') ){
        array_push($classes, $class);
    }
}
```

What I want to ask is whether this is the best practice to do what I want to do, or is there a better way? The global scope will contain a lot of other classes that isn't a child of `ParentClass`. Is looping through all declared classes the best way to go?

**EDIT** *(clarification of purpose)*:

What I want to achieve with this is to instantiate each child class extending the parent class.

I want to do `$childone = new ChildOne; $childtwo = new ChildTwo;` for every child of `ParentClass`.

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way to do it. What are you trying to do, though? Can you avoid reflection at all?

Comment: Instead of `array_push($classes, $class);` I'd go with: `$classes[] = $class;`. Anyway, code looks fine otherwise. Anyway this is kinda off-topic, IMO.

Comment: I agree with Will Vousden, reflection is going to be slow, unintuitive for your fellow developers and the IDEs can not navigate through it...

Comment: Does the edit help in clarifying my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems fine, though I'm not sure why you'd do this.  There is no easy way in php to say, 'give me all the declared classes of a certain parent class globally'  without actually checking globally each declared class.  Even if you have a couple hundred classes loaded to loop through, it shouldn't be too heavy as they're all in memory.

If you're trying to just track loaded child classes for a specific parent, why not create a registry that tracks them when they're loaded?  You could do this tracking in an autoloader or factory used for the child classes or event as a hack, just by putting something at the top of the class file before the class definition.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain further how tracking in an autoloader or factory would work? As far as I understand, autoloader is used to include undefined classes when they are being used, which is kind of different from what I want. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @jon The only way classes are declared, is if they're used somewhere.  In the autoloader, when you load the class push the class name to an array or something.  If you're not autoloading or loading them via namespace then you're just require/including the class files right?  In that case, just create a array of classnames and push the classname to the array everytime you require a certain class.

Comment: You're right to say I'm just requiring the class files. I have all the classes in a folder and I include all PHP files from that directory. The file name might not correspond to the class name found in the PHP file.

Comment: @jon hmmm... in that case, go for the hack.  Just created a registry or a an array to track them.  Then before the class definitions, push the name to the array.  Without a consistent naming convention or use of an autoloader I can't think of a non-hack way to do this outside your original solution.  If you're not experience a performance hit, you might just want to use your method.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to log the declaration of a class the first time it is loaded.
it suppose you are using autoloading.

## if you do not use composer but a custom loader :

It's the easiest way :

```
$instanciatedChildren = array();//can be a static attribute of the A class 
spl_autoload_register(function($class)use($instanciatedChildren){
   //here the code you use 
   if(is_subclass_of($class,'A')){
       $instanciatedChildren[] = $class;
   }
 }
```

## if you use composer :

you can, make a class that extends `composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php`
and then override the loadClass method to add the condition given above. and then register your new loader and unregister the old one.